# Create view that includes a list collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I need a `Create` view to capture information on a `ClubViewModel` and its occurrence schedule. I previously achieved this by flatpacking into one class however ran into issues with AutoMapper because of my flat pack single class not matching my Repository two classes.This was my previous structure which created the view:

```
public class ClubViewModel
    {
        public int ClubId { get; set; }
        public bool IsMonday { get; set; }
        public bool IsTuesday { get; set; }
        public bool IsWednesday { get; set; }
        public bool IsThursday { get; set; }
        public bool IsFriday { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? MondayFrom { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? MondayTo { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? TuesdayFrom { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? TuesdayTo { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? WednesdayFrom { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? WednesdayTo { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? ThursdayFrom { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? ThursdayTo { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? FridayFrom { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? FridayTo { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }      
    }
```

I was told I should attempt to keep the ViewModels in closer sync with my Repository Models to help with mapping later on.

Based on this, these are the two ViewModels I want to create my new `Create` view on:

```
public class ClubViewModel
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public IList<CalendarEntryViewModel> MeetingDays { get; set; }          
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}

 public class CalendarEntryViewModel
{
    public bool IsMonday { get; set; }
    public bool IsTuesday { get; set; }
    public bool IsWednesday { get; set; }
    public bool IsThursday { get; set; }
    public bool IsFriday { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }        
}
```

What I don't understand is, if I add a view for the `ClubViewModel` it will naturally exclude the List information, I'm assuming this will need to go in a partial view within the create view, however, I don't understand how I would I cater for every possible scenario as I did in my flat packed version which I was able to present nicely like so:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oldy but a goody... http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

You shouldn't need all your day flags (IsMonday, IsTuesday etc) on your MeetDay model, you can just assume which day it is based on it's position in the list. When you populate the list to pass to the view, you will create as many days as required - 7 if you want to display the full week, 5 if it's only the working week.

As long as you pass your view the same view model you expect it to return, .NET should take care of the binding magic.

Your view will look something similar to:

```
@model ClubViewModel

@for (int meetingDay = 0; meetingDay < Model.MeetingDays.Count; meetingDay++)
{
    @* Get the current day of week *@
    var dayOfWeek = Enum.GetName(typeof (DayOfWeek), meetingDay);

    <label>@dayOfWeek Start</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.MeetingDays[meetingDay].From)
    <label>@dayOfWeek Finish</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.MeetingDays[meetingDay].To)
}
```

And your controller may look something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ClubViewModel viewModel)
{
    var monday = viewModel.MeetingDays[(int)DayOfWeek.Monday];
    var tuesday = viewModel.MeetingDays[(int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday];
    // etc etc

    return View();
}
```

Haven't tested this but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: @timothyclifford Do you suggest I change my CalendarEntryView model to replace all the bools IsMonday etc with DayOfWeek

Comment: Also im trying to create a Create view now index, does this matter

Comment: Hi @SelectDistinct - Yes you can remove all the bools and instead figure out which day the entry is based on its index in the list. When you save these back to a DB etc you should use DayOfWeek, will be a cleaner/simpler data model. This should work fine for a Create view also, if you get stuck let me know